# Macintosh HD will only mount ro, because it is journaled

Tags: mount, filesystem, macbook, read-only, fsck

A little history first, I've installed 14.04 on another partition of a MacBook 5.1 because of a completely botched Mavericks upgrade which has left OS X unusable. I had to use rEFInd to get it to attempt to boot to the old (Snow Leopard, I think) OS partition, which will spin endlessly and never complete. At this point all I want to do is get some files off of the "Macintosh HD" partition from a user folder, which is of course restricted by default. chmod'ing the directory does not work because the partition mounts read-only, which I've recently discovered is because that volume is journaled, but that is what I'm trying to fix. I'm not an advanced linux user, so I'm sure there are utilities I could be using that I'm unaware of and my google fu hasn't lead me to.

First, `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o rw,remount -force /dev/sda2 /media/mac` (of course after first unmounting /dev/sda2 from the default /media/ME/Macintosh HD mount point) did not have an effect. However, adding the following line to my fstab

`UUID=61ba4438-95d6-39e5-8d60-0735e28dc132 /media/mac               hfsplus    defaults 0   2`

did manage to successfully change the mount point to /media/mac, but sadly it is still read only according to the error message I get trying to run chmod on it.

I ran `fsck -f /dev/sda2` and got this output:

`fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
** /dev/sda2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Volume check failed.`

EDIT 2:Note that I had to use the -f, running it without that tells me that the utility cannot be run because the volume is journaled. More on that below...

The Mac Disk Manager Utility (which I get to through the Mavericks install boot) reports some permissions errors, but the drive is also read only there, so it can't fix them! If someone thinks they might now how to help me, I can get the output from that process.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: a little more research has led me to understand a bit more about the root of the problem. According to various installation guides, Mavericks requires you to move to a Journaled file system. So, I'm betting during the failed installation it started (and likely finished) this conversion before something (else?) went wrong. All my research is also telling me that Ubuntu (and I presume other Linux distros) does not support mounting a journaled file system in read/write mode. There is a link to a proposed process for removing the journaling from Ubuntu [In this UbuntuForums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420673), and I'm probably going to wind up giving that a shot as painful as it sounds, but I was hoping someone could propose any other methods for either removing journaling or getting the data out of the restricted directory another way. For example, I tried using the data recovery tool in gParted with no luck.

Comment: I don't see the problem - why can't you copy the files from an RO file system in Ubuntu? I don't see why you want to chmod or similar. Your ubuntu user should have read rights anyways, in the worst case your root will be able to read. Mac file permission are not translated to ubuntu (or rather: the access permission of a mounted FS from a different OS will not be applied).

Comment: the directory is a user directory, so it's owned by a user i cannot log on as. to my knowledge, it will need to be chmod'd to become accessible, even by root.

Comment: But you have sudo rights, right?  You were using `sudo` above?

Comment: root can always read any file, regardless of any permissions set. Even on your running Ubuntu system. Try using `sudo less /foo/bar` (with the correct path), you should be able to read the file.

Comment: you are correct. I could have swarn I had run 'sudo nautilus' at some point and it had failed. that solves it. I've wasted a lot of time because I made that assumption. Thank you. Please repost that as the solution so I can award it to you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. neon_overload already posted a correct answer, feel free to accept that one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you want to do is read files from the system, so in this case, it doesn't matter (for you) that you can't mount this HFS+ partition as writable.  All you need to do is read from it.

So, mount it as you have been doing, and copy files from it using sudo, eg

```
sudo cp -av /media/mac/some-dir /home/you/some-other-dir
```

---

Edit: I realise you were assuming that you couldn't read files belonging to users from a foreign system - but you can.  With superuser rights you can read any file on a locally mounted partition.

Note that it's also possible to specify as a mount option that any users/permissions on the drive should be ignored and instead everything should be treated as belonging to a particular user using the mount options `uid=n,gid=n` where `n` is your user and group ID on the system.  This will allow you to set up a mount where you have access to everything without `sudo` (though I have never tried this on an HFS partition).

Comment: Added some extra info